# Ambiguous operator overload for std::optional?

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-overloading, option-type, c++17

Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Coptional%3E%0A%0Astruct+Test+:+public+std::optional%3Cint%3E++%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Test+o1,+o2%3B%0A++++o1+%3D%3D+o2%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g7snapshot,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7+(snapshot)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) code.

```
struct Test : public std::optional<int>  { };

Test o1, o2;
o1 == o2;
```

For the last line `gcc-7.0.1` complains with `error: ambiguous overload` pointing to two overloads for comparing an optional with a value. But shouldn't it just pick the overload with two optionals and successfully compile the code?

---

**EDIT**
Shouldn't overloads for value comparison have "guards" disallowing them to instantiate for types inherited from std::optional?

Comment: A far better question would be why are you inheriting from `optional`?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Well, in order to add some extra semantic load to it ։) Making a private member could be another option, but it is a worse option as I need all the functionality that `std::optional` provides plus I am adding some more functionality. Don't want to re-define reset(), emplace(), etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are three overloads that will be found for this expression:

```
// #1, with T=int, U=int
template <class T, class U> 
constexpr bool operator==(optional<T> const&, optional<U> const& );

// #2, with T=int, U=Test
template <class T, class U> 
constexpr bool operator==(optional<T> const&, U const& );

// #3, with T=int, U=Test
template <class T, class U> 
constexpr bool operator==(U const&, optional<T> const& );
```

`#2` and `#3` have better conversion sequences than `#1` since one of the arguments (the `U const&`) is an Exact Match for `Test` instead of a Derived-to-Base conversion.

But while we can prefer `#2` and `#3` to `#1`, there's no reason to prefer one of `#2` or `#3` to the other - each has a better conversion sequence in one argument and a worse conversion sequence in the second.

Hence, it's ambiguous. Note both `#2` and `#3` are well-formed operators, since you can indeed compare an `int` to a `Test`. To disambiguate them, you'd have to *additionally* add a constraint that `U` does not inherit from `optional<T>`, which is... a really specific constraint.

---

You can resolve this by casting one or the other `Test` to an `optional<int>`, or simply providing an `optional==(Test, Test)`.

Comment: Eventually I added `optional==(Test, Test)`, but in the library perspective shouldn't it be better to prefer classes derived from std::optional over the values for these overloads?

Comment: I thought the question (see EDIT in the question) was not why those overloads are ambiguous, but more why the committee didn't chose a different set of overloads (the same with some enable_if?) that would not be ambiguous.

Comment: @MarcGlisse An extra set of overloads *specifically* for the case where `U` inherits from `optional<T>`?

Comment: I didn't say it would be a good idea, but that's how I interpreted the question.

Comment: @Barry Yes,  An extra set of overloads for the case where `U` inherits from or is convertible to `optional<T>`.